# Xml pull parsing with customised adapter

Tags: android, parsing, rss, listadapter

Hi There I am very new to the android platform ..off late I was trying my hands on parsing rss feed using xml pull parser..My code works perfectly when I use the standard listview layout of android..but when I try to implement the same code using a customized list view and adapter ..no data is been shown..I tested my customized adapter with raw data (not the one fetch from the feed) and it works perfectly..But when I try to use the information fetched from the feed the list view doesn't show any data..Have been trying for quite some time now yet am unable to get it done..Can anyone please help me in identifying the mistakes I am committing...Mind you my app functions perfectly with non internet data but not with the ones fetch from the feed..I am trying to extract the title tag from the feed..any help will be highly appreciated...the codes are as follows

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<FeedData> headlines;
    List <String>title;
    FeedData data = new FeedData();
    List links;
    String msg =null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        title = new ArrayList<String>();
        links = new ArrayList();
        headlines = new ArrayList<FeedData>();

        DownloadTask runner =new DownloadTask();
        runner.execute();

        for(int i=0;i<title.size();i++){
            msg=title.get(i).toString();
            data.setTitle(msg);
            headlines.add(data);
        }


         FeedAdapter adapter= new    FeedAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.imagefeed,headlines);
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMyFeed);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);  

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{    URL url = new URL("http://www.pcworld.com/index.rss  ");
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // We will get the XML from an input stream
        xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");


        boolean insideItem = false;

            // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = true;
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        title.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                }
            }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG &&   xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                insideItem=false;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return null;
    }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
        public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
               try {
                   return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   return null;
                 }
            }

    }// end of DownloadTask class

      }`
```

FeedData.java

```
      public class FeedData {
    String headlines;

    public FeedData()
    {

    }
    public FeedData(String title) {
        this.headlines=title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.headlines=title;
    }
    public String getTitle(){

        return headlines;
    }

       }`

      `FeedData.java
        public class FeedData {
    String headlines;

    public FeedData()
    {

    }
    public FeedData(String title) {
        this.headlines=title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.headlines=title;
    }
    public String getTitle(){

        return headlines;
    }

        }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMyFeed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

imagefeed.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFeed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivImg"
    android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivImg"
    android:text="Headlines" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the definition of FeedAdapter.

Comment: @ Joe Malin: FeedAdapter is just a Java class where I defined my customized adapter..its just a class extending the Base adapter..dats it..

Answer (score 0):

display or set your `adapter`. `ListView` after completed `DownloadTask` means call

```
  FeedAdapter adapter= new    FeedAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.imagefeed,headlines);
  ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMyFeed);
  list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in `onPostExecute`.
The behaviour of `AsynchTask` is different thread so, your `headlines` `title` `ArrayList` is having no data that why your data is not displaying on `ListView`. So after finishing the DownloadTask set your `adapter`. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you ..It indeed was the main issue...Thank you for the  answer ..really appreciated..